# Embedding Python in C++: Failing to import from the same directory

Tags: python, c++

Within a larger class I have a section of code for importing a python script and running it. The file (animate.py) is contained within the same directory as the executable.

```
void classname::show( void )
{
         stringstream run_cmd;
         run_cmd << "animate.run('" << name << "')";

         Py_Initialize();
         PyRun_SimpleString("import animate");
         PyRun_SimpleString(run_cmd.str().c_str());
         Py_Finalize();
}
```

The thing is, I'm working through two computers, when compiled on one of these, this works fine. On my personal laptop it fails to import the scipt with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named animate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'animate' is not defined
```

They're both compiled through the exact same makefile, with the `-lpython2.7` flag used. The file structure is also the same.

Is there some library I'm missing to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the current working directory to Python path (it's not included by default):

```
     Py_Initialize();
     PyObject *sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path");
     PyList_Append(sys_path, PyString_FromString("."));
     PyRun_SimpleString("import animate");
     PyRun_SimpleString(run_cmd.str().c_str());
     Py_Finalize();
```

Comment: That certainly works for being able to import the script, but now that script can't import numpy etc. Do I have to set a path for that as well?

Comment: Also I'm still curious why this works on the other machine fine without setting the path, but not on this one.